# cellForRowAtIndexPath returning nil for invisible cells

Tags: ios, swift

I know there are multiple posts here on SO regarding this, but I didn't see a best solution for my problem, so checking if there is any.

In my case I have a long list of cells and each cell has a button on it. Button selection limit is 3, so if user selects 4th button, my code should automatically unselect the last selected button. So I was storing the last selected button's indexPath and then when user selects button on a different cell, I get the last selected button's cell and unselect the button. But if this cell is invisible, cellForRowAtIndexPath returns nil as documented.

```
Eg: lastSelectedIndexPath = IndexPath(0 , 0)

func buttonSelectionAction() {
   // lastSelectedCell is nil if button is invisible i.e. if the user has scrolled to the end of the long list.
   if let lastSelectedCell = tableView.cellForRow(lastSelectedIndexPath) as? MyCustomCell {
        lastSelectedCell.button.isSelected = false
   }
}
```

***My solution:***

To avoid this, I am storing the last selected table view cell instead of it's indexPath and I use that cell directly instead of calling cellForRow.

```
Eg: lastSelectedTableViewCell = MyCustomCell()

func buttonSelectionAction() {
   // lastSelectedCell is nil if button is invisible i.e. if the user has scrolled to the end of the long list.
   if let lastSelectedCell = lastSelectedTableViewCell {
        lastSelectedCell.button.isSelected = false
   }
}
```

However I think storing a cell is a bad practice, so I am looking for other better solution if there is any?

Comment: Don't think in **views**. Maintain all information in the data **model** and update the view in `cellForRow`

Comment: Do not store the cells directly as they can be reused so a cell you thought was displaying certain data will be reused and be displaying different data.  As said just record (data model) which buttons are selected (index path is fine) and then when it changes either reload the entire table view or if you want just the cells that are visible.  Any that are not visible will be updated when they become visible from your store information (data model).

Answer (score 0):

Cells are reusable so trying to save them is not a good idea. Instead, you should save states for the cells. So for your issue, I think you can create an array to save the selected indices, `a[0]` will save the index of the first selected button (cell),... then you will have `a[2]` for the last selected cell. Whenever a newly selected cell occurs, all you have to do is update the `a[2]` to the new cell index. When displaying buttons states, querying that array to know selected state for a particular cell. Be careful when working with array's indices.

Comment: How do you unselect the last selected button though. In the UI it is still blue. Do you mean the reload the entire tableview after storing/updating the states in the array so it unselects the button?

Comment: As we are setting the last item (`a[2]`) to the newly selected cell index, when the table view queries for that cell, it's no longer existed in the selected array so the state for it will become unselected. Of course, before setting `a[2]` to the new index, you have to query for the current cell that is going to be replaced and reset the button on that cell.

Answer (score 0):

**Issue**: You use index path while cell reusable when user scroll, be careful with index path for cell.

**Solution**: I think you should use delegate from cell for action tap button without using cellForFow.